# Debug logs not showing for VF Pages on site community

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

We have a site of type community with custom domain(that ends with Force.com) and there are couple of VF pages(**PageA & PageB**) on this community.

When a community user logs into our application(there is a custom VF login page) and lands on the home page(PageA) and clicks on a button he is taken to a second VF page(PageB) and on that VF page there is a javascript remoting happening and I am trying to debug that Javacript remoting but I am not seeing debug logs.

I added the Site to the debug logs as mentioned in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile)

But if I replace the custom domain name on the community URL with salesforce url debug logs working fine.

i.e.

http://my-community-domain.force.com/PageA -- debug logs not working.

http://cs19.salesforce.com/apex/pageA -- debug logs working.

Has anybody experienced something like this.

Comment: in debug log you need to add specific user who is using VF page in community

Comment: Thanks so much! It is working now. Please post it as answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**in debug log you need to add specific user who is using VF page in community**

So When we add specific user then only Debug generate for that user.

Comment: It is irrelevant but I want to say, I opened ticket with salesforce on this and it has been more than 6 hours and no solution yet despite having two gotomeetings with them. SFSE Rocks! :)

Comment: @javanoob I am totally agree. Community members are Rocks. If any question clear then sure anyone will give you best ans. SFSE Rocks :)