# Guest user debug logs suddenly not being created

Tags: debugging, logging, guest-user

We have a set of communities where unauthenticated users are submitting forms, and we want to set trace flags for the behavior done by these users, i.e. we want to observe what the guest users are doing in the logs.

For some time, we had logs being created properly using the method in this post:
[How can I get a debug log for the sites guest user/public profile? [updated for Winter 17]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile)

However - we deployed some small patches to the org, and logs are no longer being printed for the guest user.

Steps we've taken to attempt to fix:

1. deleted and recreated the trace for the guest user
2. flushed all existing debug logs through the tooling api
3. deleted and recreated the sharing settings that allow our user records to view the guest user's user record

Looking for anyone that has experienced this before, or has any advice on things to try,

Comment: Note the answer update: [How can I get a debug log for the sites guest user/public profile?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile). You need to set a cookie.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I cited that question within my question, and explicitly stated that we followed those steps, had it working, and it's no longer working. Please elaborate on how this is a duplicate.

Comment: You now need to set a cookie, or it won't work. Are you doing that? **[Set a Browser Cookie to Enable Debug Logging for Guest Users](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user.htm#rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user)**

Comment: I never needed to set a cookie with dev console open. Just set the logging in Setup -> Monitoring -> Logs. When Dev console it open make sure you **Uncheck - Debug -> Show My Current Logs Only**