# Debug log is not capturing the Logs

Tags: debugging, debug

I have set a Debug Log in my sandbox Org but it did not capturing any logs.

Please advice what it my be the reason for it.

Comment: Do you use Developer console ? Or Log in Setup ?

Comment: @SF_user I used Log In Setup

Comment: Is it a Site User?

Comment: @Devendra yes and I used the Site user name as the Name.

Comment: Refer following link, as there is a change in setting up debug log for Site User - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143549/debug-logs-not-working-for-site-guest-users-force-com-sites-after-the-winter-1/143550

Comment: @Devendra please put your answer into 'answer'

Comment: This has already been covered. At least half a dozen times in the last week. [How can I get a debug log for the sites guest user/public profile? \[updated for Winter 17\]](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the [Winter 17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/code_add_users_debug_log.htm) release, you need to set a server cookie in the browser to enable debug logs for Site Guest Users.

> Your public users generate a large volume of events, which can quickly
>   fill up your debug logs. For this reason, logs are collected for site
>   visitors who are using your Guest User license only when a public
>   user’s browser has a special cookie.
>
> To enable logging for a guest user:
>
> 1. Ask the user to set a browser cookie with a domain value of .force.com and a name value of debug_logs. Refer to the documentation
>      for your user’s browser for information on adding cookies. To be able
>      to add cookies, your user probably needs a browser plug-in or
>      extension.
> 2. Find the name of your Site's guest user.
>
>    a. From Setup, enter Sites in the Quick Find box, then select Sites.
>
>    b. Select your Site from the Site Label column.
>
>    c. Select Public Access Settings | View Users.
> 3. Set a user-based trace flag on the guest user.
>
>    a. From Setup, enter Debug Logs in the Quick Find box, then click
>      Debug Logs.
>
>    b. Click New.
>
>    c.cSet the Traced Entity Type to User.
>
>    d. Open the Lookup for the Traced Entity Name field, and then find
>      and select your guest user.
>
>    e. Assign a debug level to your trace flag.
>
>    f. Click Save.

You can also refer following [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for) for this release update

Comment: The proper dupe is really http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for