# How to read QR Code such that it will update a certain Salesforce field when scanned?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, rest-api, automation

Trying to use QR Code as a method to **automatically** track attendance of visitors of an event. So if visitors were to mark their attendance, they would need to use their phone to scan their individualized QR code that will be printed on the guest list next to their names.

Scanning their individualized QR Code should automatically mark the checkbox custom field e.g. "Attended__c" as ticked for the particular attendee in the SFDC records.

How do I go about doing this?

1. Visualforce page (I tried doing this but the attendee would need to have authentication and update their attendance manually) OR
2. Force.com REST API (not sure how) OR
3. Javascript (not sure how) OR
4. Other ways?

Comment: You would use a Force.com Site so hitting the specific URL causes an update without any need to log in.

Comment: Only Force.com Site needed? Do I need apex code or any extension to the StandardController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Visualforce page would work, but you would want to make a custom [Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites). Basically, you create a Site, assign the page to the Site, then you can update records as you like.

Comment: I tried adding a custom Site and assigning it to my own Domain. For some reason, it still requires authentication. That link you gave don't give any good examples on how to do it so I'm really stuck.

Comment: @compski Typically, "requires authentication" means that an error occurred in the code (usually security related). Try the info in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149).