# system debug logs won't get created if the site is browsed by guest user

Tags: visualforce, developer-console

I have VF single page application and its controller. If I login to Salesforce and click on the "Preview" button of the VF page then I will be able to see my `System.debug('...')` messages gets created when I executed through the VF page. I am seeing this logs in Developer Console logs.

However, if I browse the same VF page via a custom Site domain URL (or in another word this is how guest user would use) then I am no longer see any `System.debug('...') message generated when`guest user` execute through the page.

I have tried this [thread's suggestion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for) by doing like what it said but I don't see any logs created.

```
Go to Monitoring>Debug log.

Where you would normally put the username, put the name of the Site.

For example: If your site is called MySite, enter MySite as the user name. Shockingly undocumented, but this gives you the debug you're looking for.
```

I also try to set a browser cookie in my Chrome by adding this line

```
document.cookie="debug_logs=debug_logs;domain=dev-mydev.cs43.force.com";
```

where `dev-mydev.cs43.force.com` is my Force.come domain. And still I don't see any logs crated when I browsed via Site URL (or guest user).

I am using Summer 17 and Winter 18 Sandboxes and I have tested this on both and none of them work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You say two different thing. Is it that you get no logs or that you get logs but no debug statements?

Comment: I dont see any log

Comment: Do you see any logs in Setup > Debug Logs?

Comment: So I created a Debug Long in Setup setting the `user` as `name of the site` and what I see is that each time I open/ or refresh my site then I get a log created in Debug Log. This seems to me like a generic log that gets created each time a site is launched/ or refreshed. And I do not see any other log created following that.