# How to Debug SOAP UI

Tags: apex, soap-api, soap, debug, debug-logs

Is it possible to run the debug log on a SOAP UI call? I assume not because it is an external service but, because it is calling apex classes, I feel like there should be a way to look at the logs.

The reason why I ask is because I am having difficulty finding the location of a null value within my apex with the little information I am getting back from my SOAP UI response.

I've tried running the debug on myself, as the APEX class, trigger, and automated process. Because the call out is failing it does not seem to fully process.

UPDATE:
I found this post [How can I get a debug log for the sites guest user/public profile? [updated for Spring 18]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for) and this article https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user.htm that explains you need to set up a cookie on the browser and enable site guest access. I have yet to get it to work, I might be setting the cookie wrong....

[image]

Comment: How is the SOAP UI call being authenticated to Salesforce? Is it using a Session ID or is the Apex web service hosted on a public site?

Comment: It is a POST and I pass it two parameters and a body

Comment: Unless the POST is being sent to a public site hosted Apex web service you will need to authenticate the request with a SessionID or Access Token in the body. That Session ID will be associated with a Salesforce user. That then defines who you should be logging for.

Comment: I don't believe I am authenticating with either. I am just hitting an endpoint and resource (see picture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments that you aren't providing any Session ID or Access Token as part of the POST request from SOAP UI I'm assuming you are using an Apex web service that is hosted on a public site.

As such, until [Spring '18 is released](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user.htm), you will need to include a cookie in the request to activate logging.

Use the cookie format defined in [Set a Browser Cookie to Enable Debug Logging for Guest Users](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user.htm#rn_forcecom_debugging_guest_user) and the SOAP UI Request header functionality at the bottom of the request window.

[image: Setting a request Cookie in SOAP UI]

Comment: thank you! I was setting the cookie name wrong. This solved my debugging issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set debug logs from `Setup->Debug Logs`. You should setup the logs for the user whose credentials you are using to consume your Salesforce Org's API from SOUP UI.