# SFDX: Get Apex Debug Logs for Site Guest User in VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

How do I get Debug Logs for Site Guest User in VS Code? I ran `SFDX: Get Apex Debug Logs` and I can see debug logs for my user. But what I want is debug logs for Site Guest User which I don't see in the suggested results.

[image]

Comment: When you tested with your guest user did you set the cookie in their browser? See here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for

Comment: Spring'18 revokes it: `Your public users no longer need a debug_logs browser cookie to trigger logging. ` And I see the debug logs for the Guest User in Salesforce org. I just cannot download them via SFD CLI in VS Code locally.