# Logging Solution for Force.com Public RESTful webservice

Tags: rest-api, callout, webservices, force.com-sites, apexrest

I've created a public site with a RESTful service mentioned in this [blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html), however this site uses Guest User License and I can't see any debug statements when this webservice is used by Postman.

Is this intended or am I missing something? Is there way to track the callouts made without using a custom object for logging?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@HttpPost
global static String doPost() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    Blob body = req.requestBody;
    String requestString = body.toString();

    BO_LeadFormWebservice wrapper = (BO_LeadFormWebservice) JSON.deserialize(requestString, BO_LeadFormWebservice.class);
    System.debug('incoming payload');
    System.debug(wrapper);

    String result;

    if(wrapper.google_key != null){
        result = wrapper.google_key;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking at this in the future, this post has solved my issue: [StackExchange Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for). You need to set your site name as your as the user name and it will show up in debug logs (without setting a cookie).

Comment: Every force.com site has a guest user which needs to be selected for the debug logs. _set your site name as your as the user name_: this statement is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

No debug logs available for guest user since Winter 17 as the latest answer to [this question](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000Xdp9QAC) explains.
So, your best shot is a try/catch + custom log.-

Comment: As a possible solution, I found this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for)

Comment: Oh, very useful! Thanks for sharing