# Visualforce Page need authentication in Sites created in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, force.com-sites

I have two Visualforce pages displayed as PDF in a Lightning component which is eventually retrieved as a Site. However, it requires the authentication when external users try to access the VF page. Visualforce pages are already enabled for Guest User profile, however still we are prompted to enter login details when user try to access it.

Below is the existing technical background,

1. Lightning button is available in the Lightning component,

`<lightning:button label="Print" onclick="{!c.printSiteReg}"></lightning:button>`

2. URL of the VF page is called in the controller method,

   ```
   var objId = component.get("v.insertedSite.Id");
   var url = 'https://firstsolar--servicecld-- 
              c.cs47.visual.force.com/apex/SiteRegistrationPDF?id='+objId;

   window.open(url);
   ```
3. Access enabled for VF pages in guest user's profile.
   [image]
   This is a major burden for our process as Site is created for external users, whom they they are not users in our orgs.

Any idea on what is wrong or missing here?

Your comments are greatly appreciated. Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

You should able to display the landing page from your Force.com site's URL without logging in with `Guest User License`. I was trying to create debug logs using Force.com sites because it needed a webhook integration without authentication.

Maybe these posts will help;

[How can I get a debug log for the sites guest user/public profile? [updated for Spring 18]](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-can-i-get-a-debug-log-for-the-sites-guest-user-public-profile-updated-for)

[Logging Solution for Force.com Public RESTful webservice](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289299/logging-solution-for-force-com-public-restful-webservice)